# What is the correct way to handle large json strings in vert.x?

Tags: java, json, vert.x

I have a large (Currently 2MB in size, might grow up to 10MB) JSON object (containing an array of objects) from an HTTP API I need to work with:

```
client.get(...)
      .send(ar -> {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(ar.result().bodyAsBuffer());
      });
```

This results in an error:

```
Jan 09, 2020 2:11:14 PM io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a value
at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 70674, column: 27]
at io.vertx.core.json.Json.decodeValue(Json.java:222)
at io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject.fromBuffer(JsonObject.java:975)
at io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject.<init>(JsonObject.java:85)
```

I think this error occurs because of how large the JSON string is as the Json string appears to be valid. Is there a way in vert.x to handle large Json Strings/files? Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: It seems the JSON content is invalid. Have you tried to save the result in a file to see if the content is downloaded correctly?

Comment: You are in fact right. I had checked it and it looked good, check it multiple times and one of the tools I was using to check claimed it was valid too (won't be using that again), turns out there was a bug in the API I was using that resulted in an empty double field being populated with blank instead of null. Reported to the developers of the API, and they fixed it last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON was invalid but the tool being used to validate the JSON manually did not catch this.

The error was with the third party api, when a double field was blank it would leave the value for the key blank instead of null.

This:

```
{ 
  "String": "string",
  "Double": ,
  "AnotherDouble": 0.1
}
```

should be this:

```
{ 
  "String": "string",
  "Double": null,
  "AnotherDouble": 0.1
}
```

Fix was to report the invalid JSON to the developers who patched the issue making blank values null instead of blank.

Answer (score -1):

10 MB json file might be large on a mobile device.

You should be using `JsonArray` instead of `JsonObject` in your code:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(ar.result().bodyAsBuffer())
```

Comment: to be clear its a JsonObject containing a JsonArray of JsonObjects. `{ "data": [{},...] }` and this code is entirely server-side. I need to load this data to perform an audit check for changes to be made.

Comment: what is around this position `line: 70674, column: 27` in your json file?

Comment: Just the ending of one object beginning of another `70674: },
    70675: {` Json string is 111808 lines long (formatted)